# RabbitMQ: Is delivery-mode part of the firehose notification format?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have read http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html and managed to trace some messages into a queue. I was looking to find out the "delivery-mode" (Non-persistent (1) or persistent (2).) of the messages. However, I can't see it in the firehose notification format. Is it supposed to be there?

Example:

```
Properties
headers:
exchange_name:  myresults
routing_keys:
properties:
headers:
x-received-from:
uri:    amqp://obscured1.net/%2F
exchange:   myresults
redelivered:    false
cluster-name:   rabbit@obscured2.net
node:   rabbit@b7
vhost:  /
connection: rabbit@b7.3.351.0
channel:    1
user:   none
routed_queues:  myresults-c-v2
Payload: {.............}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delivery mode is one of the [content properties](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#class.basic) (a.k.a. message properties, basic properties).

Comment: So, that's a "yes, it should be there"?
So, when it isn't - what happens? Is there a default? Seems to me that the default is non-persistent (1).